# Solve $\sqrt{a+bx}+\sqrt{b+cx}+\sqrt{c+ax}=\sqrt{b-ax}+\sqrt{c-bx}+\sqrt{a-cx}$

Tags: radicals

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be real and positive parameters. Solve the equation

$$\sqrt{a+bx}+\sqrt{b+cx}+\sqrt{c+ax}=\sqrt{b-ax}+\sqrt{c-bx}+\sqrt{a-cx}$$

What could I do? Should take the square of both sides?

Comment: Hint: $x=0$ is solution (trivial solution). LHS is increasing on $x$; RHS is decreasing on $x$. So, $x=0$ is unique solution.

Answer (score 2):

Oleg567's comment & hint as answer.

$x=0\,$ is a (trivial) solution.
The LHS is increasing in $x$; the RHS is decreasing in $x$. So, $x=0$ is unique solution.